# iOS copyItemAtPath fails most of the times even if directory exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsfilemanager, copy-item

I am working on an app in which I copy downloaded file from a custom temp directory to another directory.
Custom temp directory path:

```
/Users/anujkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/37CD1D7D-1A11-4C3F-B30E-3BD9982C3E04/data/Containers/Data/Application/3E79DBB7-9B45-47F6-B6A8-85F54B8597C8/Documents/temp
```

Destination directory path:

```
/Users/anujkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/37CD1D7D-1A11-4C3F-B30E-3BD9982C3E04/data/Containers/Data/Application/3E79DBB7-9B45-47F6-B6A8-85F54B8597C8/Documents/CommonDocs
```

I don't know whats wrong with the method copyItemAtPath, it fails most of the times with error:

"The file “publicresource” doesn’t exist." even though file named "publicresource" exists.

I am running on simulator for debugging but the same scenario also happens in device.
My code is

```
BOOL isCopied = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:pathToFile toPath:destinationPath error:&error];
```

I have also tried moveItemAtPath but the issue remain same.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats the error description ??? You checked ???

Comment: how are you creating your path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue, sometimes my destination directory was not getting created, I had added the code in application didFinishLaunchin for creating that directory but sometimes it was getting failed to create so.
So i added the code to create that directory before downloading the file and problem is solved not.

Thanks